# How can I loop over entries in JSON?

Tags: python, json

I want to loop over the content of a JSON file and print it to the console.

I think I did mix up something with lists.

This is what I tried to get all the `team_name` elements

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import json

url = 'http://openligadb-json.heroku.com/api/teams_by_league_saison?league_saison=2012&league_shortcut=bl1'
response = urlopen(url)
json_obj = json.load(response)

for i in json_obj['team']:
    print i
```

And this is my JSON (simplified:)

```
{
    "team": [
        {
            "team_icon_url": "http://www.openligadb.de/images/teamicons/Hamburger_SV.gif",
            "team_id": "100",
            "team_name": "Hamburger SV"
        },
        {
            "team_icon_url": "http://www.openligadb.de/images/teamicons/FC_Schalke_04.gif",
            "team_id": "9",
            "team_name": "FC Schalke 04"
        }
    ]
}
```

(Full JSON output to be found here: [Link](http://openligadb-json.heroku.com/api/teams_by_league_saison?league_saison=2012&league_shortcut=bl1))

And of course I get an error, that I should use integer input in [], not string, but I don't get how I could do that.

```
for i in json_obj['team']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Here is the `response`:

```
http://openligadb-json.heroku.com/api/teams_by_league_saison?league_saison=2012&league_shortcut=bl1
<addinfourl at 139755086292608 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f1b446d33d0>>
```

What did I get wrong?

Comment: Can you print the `response`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the simplified JSON excerpt you provided (after having fixed the syntax error in it).

Comment: i ran this and it worked for me. what version of Python?

Comment: Works for me, too. Check the types of json_obj and json_obj['team']. Try with the json snippet you pasted first, disabling the HTTP request. It might not always return what you expect.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.3, on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: It works on my environment, too. Can you print out the json_obj['team']?

Comment: That won't help. You want to print `response`.

Comment: Oddly, if I follow my own code line by line in command prompt, I get the right output. Just when I use a script written in Gedit, I get the above mentioned error. I will rewrite it and report...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Actually, to query the `team_name`, just add it in brackets to the last line. Apart from that, it seems to work on Python 2.7.3 on command line.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import json

url = 'http://openligadb-json.heroku.com/api/teams_by_league_saison?league_saison=2012&league_shortcut=bl1'
response = urlopen(url)
json_obj = json.load(response)

for i in json_obj['team']:
    print i['team_name']
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this :

```
import urllib, urllib2, json
url = 'http://openligadb-json.heroku.com/api/teams_by_league_saison?league_saison=2012&league_shortcut=bl1'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('User-Agent','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)')
request.add_header('Content-Type','application/json')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
json_object = json.load(response)
#print json_object['results']
if json_object['team'] == []:
    print 'No Data!'
else:
    for rows in json_object['team']:
        print 'Team ID:' + rows['team_id']
        print 'Team Name:' + rows['team_name']
        print 'Team URL:' + rows['team_icon_url']
```

Comment: hi, where module urllib and urllib2?

Answer (score 0):

To decode json, you have to pass the json string. Currently you're trying to pass an object:

```
>>> response = urlopen(url)
>>> response
<addinfourl at 2146100812 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x7fe8cc2c>>
```

You can fetch the data with `response.read()`.

Comment: I thought I converted the string to json with json.load - could you please give me a hint how to realize your solutions?