# grab values in json

Tags: python

I have the following json in this format:

```
{
    "HATg": {
        "id": "208-2", 
        "code": "225a"
        "state" : True
    }, 
    "PROPEMPTY": {
        "id": "208-3", 
        "code": "225b"
        "state" False
    }
}
```

Was wondering how do I access/grab both the `id` and `code` as I iterate each items in the file in a pythonic way? Like `for i in items...`

By the way, the contents in the json file differ as it is manipulate by user adding in different contents. Apologize in advance if I am not using any terms as I am not sure what they are called

Comment: have you seen this ? https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I loop over entries in JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547916/how-can-i-loop-over-entries-in-json)

Comment: This is not valid JSON.

Comment: Sorry about that. Saw the file format is "json" and I have happily assumed that it is valid JSON

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "JSON" looks more like this:

```
{
    "HATg": {
        "id": "208-2",
        "code": "225a",
        "state": true
    },
    "PROPEMPTY": {
        "id": "208-3",
        "code": "225b",
        "state": false
    }
}
```

and that you have succesfully parsed it into a Python object (for example, by using `j = json.load(jsonfile)`), then it's trivial to iterate through it in Python (assuming Python 3):

```
>>> for key, value in j.items():
...     print("{}: {}, {}".format(key, value['id'], value['code']))
...
PROPEMPTY: 208-3, 225b
HATg: 208-2, 225a
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a python dictionary and not a json. You can iterate them like this:

```
    a = {
    "HATg": {
        "id": "208-2",
        "code": "225a",
        "state" : True
    },
    "PROPEMPTY": {
        "id": "208-3",
        "code": "225b",
        "state" : False
    }
}

for i in a:
    print i
    print a[i]['id'], a[i]['code']
```

This will give the output as

```
PROPEMPTY
208-3 225b
HATg
208-2 225a
```