# loop in json after using JSON.Parser

Tags: django, rest, parsing, django-rest-framework

I'm Using [Rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to get `JSON` data and parse them. now I don't know how to access the second argument of json data, for parse the json I've seen [this link.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/)

code in views:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@parser_classes((JSONParser,))
def product_list(request):
    """
    List all products which name of them is in the json data
    """

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.data)
        MarketProduct=[]
        for item in request.data:
            print(item)
            try:
                product=Market.objects.get(name=item)
                MarketProduct.append(product)
            except Market.DoesNotExist:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer = MarketSerializer(MarketProduct, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

code in urls:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^listproducts/$', views.product_list),


]
```

here in this line: 
 `for item in request.data:`
the `item` only has the first argument of each json.

the json which I've sent is :

```
{'hello': '1', 'bye': '2'}
```

in printing items , only "hello" and "bye" prints.but i want to access "1" and "2" too.

It's important for me to use Django framework. 
and I can't get the appropriate way to use [`json.load(raw)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547916/how-can-i-loop-over-entries-in-json) in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with parsing JSON. DRF has already parsed the JSON into a Python dict, and you'd get exactly the same result if you used `json.loads`.

When you iterate through a dict, you just get the keys. To get the values as well, you need to iterate through `.items()`:

```
for item, value in request.data.items():
        print(item, value)
```