# How to load data exported from Firebase as json into Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have exported some log data from a Firebase app to a json file. The file structure looks like this:

```
{
    "-LT3ty7Hma7uXWDHmJjH": {
        "id": "-LT3ty7Hma7uXWDHmJjH",
        "message": "jo",
        "time": 1544123048630
    },
    "-LT3tzmgUQkHJaaYBY6d": {
        "id": "-LT3tzmgUQkHJaaYBY6d",
        "message": "bla bla bla",
        "time": 1544123055429
    },
    ...
}
```

**Problem:** When i use this code ...

```
import json

arr = json.loads("log.json")
print(arr)
```

... i get the error message `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. I tried replacing the curly braces at the very end with square brackets to make it an array, same error.

**Goal:** In the end, want to get a python list of dictionaries like this:

```
[

    {
        "id": "-LT3ty7Hma7uXWDHmJjH",
        "message": "jo",
        "time": 1544123048630
    },
    {
        "id": "-LT3tzmgUQkHJaaYBY6d",
        "message": "bla bla bla",
        "time": 1544123055429
    },
    ...
]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks or your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing Firebase JSON with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095497/parsing-firebase-json-with-python)

Comment: don't care man, i have the result in 2 lines :)

Comment: if it works for you, put as correct answer please :)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately somehow the Firebase json file does not work with the `loads()` command, only with `open()` and `json.load()`.

Comment: man you putted resolved green check in another answer and my answer was answered first and have more likes and is more simply than the other. You ask to change dict with keys to dict without keys. you failed in another thing, but I resolved the real problem .

Now i changed loads() to load() , but the real solution is write ```contain = arr.values()```
and

```contain = [*contain]```

I dont know why you didnt give me green check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the result in 2 lines, try it :) :

```
import json

arr = json.load("log.json")
print(arr)

contain = arr.values()
contain = [*contain]
print(contain)
```

Console:

```
[
    {
        'id': '-LT3ty7Hma7uXWDHmJjH', 
        'message': 'jo', 
        'time': 1544123048630
    }, 
    {
        'id': '-LT3tzmgUQkHJaaYBY6d', 
        'message': 'bla bla bla', 
        'time': 1544123055429
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

the json file is invalid the correct is :

```
{

    "-LT3ty7Hma7uXWDHmJjH": [
        {
        "id": "-LT3ty7Hma7uXWDHmJjH",
        "message": "jo",
        "time": 1544123048630
        }
    ],
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to convert that json file to a list, you can try:

```py
import json

if __name__ == "__main__":

    json_file = open("log.json")
    dic = json.load(json_file)
    print(dic)

    arr = []

    for item in dic:
        arr.append(dic[item])

    print(arr)
```